# how to export all xhr request In chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, request, xmlhttprequest

I want to get all the xhr requests in chrome after the page load finished. 
they can be shown in chrometool -> network -> XHR.
is there a way to do that?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180685/exporting-xhrs-from-chrome-to-raw-file